# django login_required decorator next parameter not getting matched

Tags: django, django-login

## TL;DR

for a view X having decorator login_required(`view Y's url`) i am unable to redirect to Y, please refer the image below

## background

a django app named ncqs has a login_view, which handles the get and post request for a user login

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print "username:",username,"password",password
        return login_user(request, username, password)
    return render(request, 'ncqs/login.html')
```

the code for login_user is not shown for simplicity (btw, it is taken from another stackoverflow answer)

i have included

```
LOGIN_URL = '/ncqs/login'
```

in my settings.py file

## problem

whenever i try to access /ncqs/start without user logging in, i get 404
[image]

## work around

by removing the trailing slash  and dollar sign after login in urls.py i was able to workaround this issue

i think the problem is with the trailing slash that gets appended at the end of the url .../ncqs/start/ which is causing this problem

i am using custom template and view, not the one provided by django auth. also i am not using django forms but my own custom form

please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your url pattern for login has a trailing slash, e.g.

```
url('^login/$, login_view, name='login'),
```

you need to include that trailing slash on your `LOGIN_URL` setting.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/ncqs/login/'
```

Another option is to use the url pattern name, which avoids hardcoding the url in your settings.

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
```

Comment: i figured this on my own. btw, i tried to implement "avoid-hardcoding-url" approach by using reverse('login') but it gave an exception that no apps are loaded. i think i will stick to LOGIN_URL = "login".

Comment: You can't use `reverse` in the settings, because the URL config hasn't been loaded yet. You can use `reverse_lazy('login')`, but it's simpler to use `'login'`, and Django will take care of reversing the url for you.